# I hate human beings how can I develop metta?

Tags: metta

I don't like human beings because of their ego centric nature. They have destroyed nature- plants, species, morality, love, harmony etc. I just wish whole human species vanish or come to end. They have messed up the perfect nature. How can I develop love or Metta towards human beings? What are the ways by which I can develop love towards who are not doing such works to be loved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted a few times recently, to focus on developing equanimity (*upekkha*). Unlike Abrahamic religions, Buddhism teaches what [creates the (social) world](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.044.than.html) is [*ignorance*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.001.than.html). In Buddhism, that people are ignorant is just the way things naturally are. It is the true nature of the world (refer to the [*Lokavagga*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.13.budd.html)). Buddhism teaches people who are truly humane or human are "rare" ([SN 56.47](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn56.47)).

Therefore, Buddhism instructs to practise equanimity (*upekkha*) to free the mind of irritation & aversion. Once this is done, more positive mental states can be practised, such as forgiveness, to remove hatred & cruelty. When hatred & cruelty are removed, metta & compassion will arise.

'Metta' ('friendliness') is a social value, which can be difficult to practise in today's world, which has become extremely immoral & corrupt over the last 30 years or so.

> *This was said by the Blessed One, said by the Arahant, so I have heard: "The Tathagata — worthy & rightly self-awakened — has two Dhamma discourses given in sequence. Which two?*
>
> *'See evil as evil.' This is the first Dhamma discourse. 'Having seen evil as evil, become disenchanted there, dispassionate there, released.' This is the second Dhamma discourse.*
>
> *These are the two Dhamma discourses that the Tathagata — worthy & rightly self-awakened — has given in sequence."*
>
> [Iti 39](https://suttacentral.net/en/iti39)

Answer (score 0):

You sholud know the difference characterizes  between wisdom with metta and hate.

Metta is practitioner's consciousness that thinking to **make happy consciousness** arise in **the other lives**. (sukhī attānaṃ pariharantu)

There are the same and the difference characterizes  between wisdom with metta and hate.

1. Wisdom clearly comprehensions about cons (unwholesome consciousness) & pros (wholesome consciousness).

   Hate see only cons, cons of pros, and pros of hate.
2. Wisdom never love anything.

   Hate love it's beloved such as you love the world, hate it's enemy such as you hate human being.
3. Wisdom with metta clearly comprehensions about the cons of hate, **but never hate people who having cons.**

   Hate see  the cons of people, and hate both people and cons.

Have you ever see the pros of your enemy such as  "they still not kill you"? That is the pros but you never thinking of it, because you hate your enemy's pros, too.